# iOS 4 Utilize AVCam demo in own code

Tags: iphone, hibernate, view, avfoundation

I'm new to iOs development and wondered if anybody has taken the AVCam demo and integrated into their own project?
I would like to integrate it with my current project and pop up the AVCamView when the user hits a particular button. How do I do that?
Any code snippets would be very appreciated!!!

Regards,
Lars

Comment: Did you get this working in your app? I am attempting the same, and I get tons of lag before the phone is ready to take photos/video

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the files into your project (exclude the appDelegate file)
2. `AVCamDemoViewController *camViewController = [[AVCamViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:cameViewController animated:YES]`

I haven't tried it myself, but that should work. Make sure you #import the files.